# Developer Branch vs. Feature Branch

Tags: version-control, git, branching, mercurial

I saw around that development teams usually use source control in one of 2 schemes:

Either "Feature Branch", where each feature is developed in a new branch, or "Developer Branch", where each developer in the team has a dedicated branch for his work.

I understand the technical differences, but I don't really understand when it's better to use each scheme.

I mainly use HG, but I don't think it matters

Comment: You could argue that you're always using developer branches using git, hg or similair. Since locally everyone always has their own branches.

Answer (score 12):

From my experience, feature branches are strictly more general-purpose and flexible. The advantage is that feature branches allow for a developer to work on multiple branches concurrently - and even for multiple developers to be working on the same branch, if needed, without confusion ("Why is `Joe` writing commits on the `Bob` branch...?").

Using developer-specific branches, although it is simpler initially, can cause friction when many features are being worked on simultaneously (things like `git stash` can be used to somewhat avoid this, but at the cost of lowered transparency).

And perhaps one of the more important issues is that you lose a bit of semantic information when using developer-specific branches. The line:

```
git merge topnav-style-change
```

is simple and can help to avoid mistakes (it could not, for example, be easily confused with the branch `massive-refactoring`). On the other hand,

```
git merge joe
```

does not convey much by itself ("Was it Joe or Bob who was working on the style changes...?").

For these kinds of reasons, in general, I see more projects nowadays using feature branches. However, the two choices are not necessarily exclusive - they could be used together as-is, or even in some kind of hybrid mix. It really depends on the complexity and needs of your project.